# GraphQL Type doesn't match Mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, graphql

I have these types and query:

```
type Post {
    id: ID!
    author: User!
    description: String!
    createdAt: String!
    picture: String!
    likes: Int!
    comments: [Comment]!
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    password: String!
    name: String!
    username: String!
    createdAt: String!
    age: Int!
    posts: [Post]!
    comments: [Comment]!
    images: [Image]!
    followers: [Follower]!
    following: [Following]!
}
```

And this is how they are linked in my Mongoose Schema / MongoDB:

```
const postSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      auto: false,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    picture: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    author: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    likes: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    comments: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    collection: "Posts",
  }
);
```

The problem is at ***author***

Basically, whenever I create a Post, the author field is saved as a string that is a reference to a User ID. All good until I have to make a query on the frontend:

```
export const GET_ALL_POSTS = gql`
  query {
    getAllPosts {
      picture
      id
      description
      createdAt
      likes
      author {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

The problem is that in the database, author is saved as a String even though in my Mongoose I try to save it as a ObjectID reference. So, when I do my query and I want the 'author', I can't query just the 'author' because in my typedefs, the author is an Object and it requires a subfield (which it doesn't work because in my database the author is a string) and if I try to query it just as String, I can't because GraphQL thinks that author is an object with subfields.

Any way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Mongoose has an option populate that you can use to call an object by it's id inside another object. All in one call.